# PyGTK Curve memory error

Tags: python, memory, pygtk

i need to draw a graph. and i use gtk.Curve widget for this. and when i add him a long vector it gives me this error:

> GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.26.1/glib/gmem.c:170: failed to allocate 4294967276 bytes
>   aborting...

the code is simple:

```
w = gtk.Window()
c = gtk.Curve()
c.set_vector(v)
c.set_curve_type(gtk.CURVE_TYPE_SPLINE)
w.add(c)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

the vector is a long list:

> [0.80000000000000004, 0.29999999999999999, 0.29999999999999999, 0.80000000000000004, 0.90000000000000002, 0.20000000000000001, ...]

about 800 elements in this list. can anyone know whats the problem? thx

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why but gtk.Curve does not seem to be able to  manipulate data outside of the main loop.  Try something like this to add the data after the main call.

```
import random, gtk, gobject

def createCurve(c):
    v = [random.random() for i in range(800)]
    c.set_vector(v)
    c.set_curve_type(gtk.CURVE_TYPE_SPLINE)
    return True

c = gtk.Curve()
vb = gtk.VBox()
vb.pack_start(c, True, True)
w = gtk.Window()
w.add(vb)
w.show_all()
gobject.timeout_add(2000, createCurve, c)
gtk.main()
```

Comment: it works well, but i dont know why the **Curve** is showing just a few point and the vector has 800 points. [SCREENSHOT](http://www.st.fmph.uniba.sk/~magyar2/Images/test.png)

Comment: @microo8, it is showing you "fitted" points, not the raw data.  If you switch to gtk.CURVE_TYPE_FREE, you can see each individual point.